# Catching an inner exception - but only if there is one!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, exception

I am trying to catch an exception but occasionally get an inner exception. I want to output both into a label.
I often get Object reference not set to instance of an object if there is no inner exception.

```
Catch ex As Exception
          exError = ex.Message.ToString
          If Not ex.InnerException.Message Is Nothing Then
     exError &= "<br/>" & ex.InnerException.Message.ToString

                End If

                Return View()
            End Try
```

Comment: Writing exception details to the client goes against security best practices. It gives an attacker details about the inner workings of your application.

Comment: Sometimes that's where the info that the client needs is, though. In the best of all possible worlds you could anticipate every eventuality and write a custom string to the client or log, but....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
 If Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing Then
     exError &= "<br/>" & ex.InnerException.Message.ToString
 End If
```

Or, as StingyJack pointed out:

```
If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
   exError &= "<br/>" & ex.InnerException.Message.ToString
End If
```

Comment: Or "If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then"... less mistakes when reading "IsNot"

Answer (score 1):

Since MattC's answer doesn't really specify the reason why your code isn't working:

You are getting the "Object reference not set to instance of an object" error due to the `ex.InnerException.Message` part; if "ex.InnerException" is null, it won't have a "Message".

Anytime you're trying to get several levels down objects you don't know whether exist or not, you need to build up to it (i.e. ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.Message != null, etc)

Comment: && is AndAlso and || is OrElse in VB.Net. Its important to know the difference, especially when null checking.